# Fortran Runtime Error during read from file

Tags: io, fortran, runtime-error

I'm trying to read in a .gro file which looks like this:

```
1coh      C    1   0.206  -0.049   0.429
1coh     O1    2   0.295   0.048   0.501
1coh     H3    3   0.252  -0.137   0.424
1coh     H4    4   0.186  -0.014   0.337
```

I need to store the `0.206`,  `-0.049`,   `0.429` into arrays.
I use this to recognise the `coh` in the lines:

```
open(unit=20,file=grofile2)
   do i=1,3
      read(20,'(A)')line
      lname2=line(6:8)
   enddo
close(unit=20)
```

Then, read in the specific lines using:

```
     open(unit=20,file=grofile2)
150  read(20,'(A)',end=151)line
     if(line(6:8).eq.lname2)then
        i=i+1
        lig2(i)=line
        write(*,*)lig2(i)
     endif
     goto 150
151  continue
     close(unit=20)
     natoms2=i
```

The `write` here does output the lines to the terminal correctly.
I then follow this with:

```
do j=1,natoms2
   write(*,*) j
   write(*,*) lig2(j)
   read(lig2(j)(23:28),*)lig2x(j)
   read(lig2(j)(31:36),*)lig2y(j)
   read(lig2(j)(39:44),*)lig2z(j)
   write(*,*) lig2x(j),lig2y(j),lig2z(j)
enddo
```

to read the individual values to these arrays.

At this point I get the error:

```
At line 145 of file samgen.f
Fortran runtime error: Bad real number in item 1 of list input
```

Line 145 is:`read(lig2(j)(23:28),*)lig2x(j)`

This syntax has worked for this file in a different program, but is not working here. I've tried using `F6.3` instead of `*` in the read line. I've checked for variable declarations and types. What am I doing wrong? Any ideas? Or possibly a better way to read this in?

Comment: Have you checked the value of `lig2(j)(23:28)`?

Comment: What is the value of `i` before the line `150 read(...`. Because if it's not 0 before (might be 3 because you used it in the do loop before), then `lig2(1)` is not assigned a value, which will make it hard to read a floating point value out of it.

Comment: Yes, columns 23 through 28 of that first input line look like: '06  -0'. This is not a valid number. I am familiar with .gro files. You can control the output precision and that changes the formatting so this program may work on 1 .gro file but not another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take 'test.gro' file as an example.

```
1coh      C    1   0.206  -0.049   0.429
1coh     O1    2   0.295   0.048   0.501
1coh     H3    3   0.252  -0.137   0.424
1coh     H4    4   0.186  -0.014   0.337
```

"I need to store the 0.206, -0.049, 0.429 into arrays." I did not understand what follows in your question. Does this quite simple code do what you need?

```
program read
character :: char1*5, char2*3
integer :: i1
real :: r1, r2, r3

open (30, FILE='test.gro', STATUS='OLD')
    do i=1,4
    ! I would read without format specification: it is much easier
    ! though type of variable must be correct!
      read(30,*)  char1, char2, i1, r1, r2,r3 
         !test what I have read:
      print*, char1, char2, i1, r1, r2, r3 
    end do
close (30)
end program
```